# "\r\n" appears as small square boxes in word document, C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose

I am appending some text containing '\r\n' into a word document at run-time.
But when I see the word document, they are replaced with small square boxes :-(

I tried replacing them with `System.Environment.NewLine` but still I see these small boxes.

Any idea?

Comment: We'll need to know how you're "appending some text".

Comment: hard to tell what the problem is.. are you using wingdings?

Comment: Thanks all, I was using Aspose.Words for string manipulation and copying over to new document. strText.Replace("\r\n", Aspose.Words.ControlChar.LineBreak) solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

the answer is to use `\v` - it's a paragraph break.

Comment: ps - i realise this was asked over a year ago.. just thought it would help anyone else looking for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you not tried one or the other in isolation i.e.`\r` or `\n` as Word will interpret a carriage return and line feed respectively. The only time you would use the Environment.Newline is in a pure ASCII text file.  Word would handle those characters differently! Or even a Ctrl+M sequence. Try that and if it does not work, please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Word uses the `<w:br/>` XML element for line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, here is a function that sets the text for a Word XML node, and takes care of multiple lines:

```
//Sets the text for a Word XML <w:t> node
//If the text is multi-line, it replaces the single <w:t> node for multiple nodes
//Resulting in multiple Word XML lines
private static void SetWordXmlNodeText(XmlDocument xmlDocument, XmlNode node, string newText)
{

    //Is the text a single line or multiple lines?>
    if (newText.Contains(System.Environment.NewLine))
    {
        //The new text is a multi-line string, split it to individual lines
        var lines = newText.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        //And add XML nodes for each line so that Word XML will accept the new lines
        var xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int count = 0; count < lines.Length; count++)
        {
            //Ensure the "w" prefix is set correctly, otherwise docFrag.InnerXml will fail with exception
            xmlBuilder.Append("<w:t xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml\">");
            xmlBuilder.Append(lines[count]);
            xmlBuilder.Append("</w:t>");

            //Not the last line? add line break
            if (count != lines.Length - 1)
            {
                xmlBuilder.Append("<w:br xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml\" />");
            }
        }

        //Create the XML fragment with the new multiline structure
        var docFrag = xmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment();
        docFrag.InnerXml = xmlBuilder.ToString();
        node.ParentNode.AppendChild(docFrag);

        //Remove the single line child node that was originally holding the single line text, only required if there was a node there to start with
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }
    else
    {
        //Text is not multi-line, let the existing node have the text
        node.InnerText = newText;
    }
}
```